# Please tell me what type of data you need to use? to output data from Firebase, I get the same results((

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am writing an appendix with a class schedule. I need to display information on cards.
at the moment, I get the same result from the database.

**body.dart**

```
child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('lessons').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            return GridView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                  childAspectRatio: 2.55),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return LessonBundelCard(
                  lesson: snapshot.data.documents,
                  press: () {},
                );
              },
            );
          }),
    ))
  ],
);
}
}
```

1.what type of data should be in lesson?
2.i don't understand what type i need to use

```
**lesson_bundel_cart.dart**

class LessonBundelCard extends StatelessWidget {
final LessonBundelCard lesson;
final Function press;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the type LessonBundelCard for the field lesson. I think you should add fromJson method inside your model class (LessonBundelCard), and then use that to get the required lesson from Firestore.

So, after adding fromJson method, you should use:

```
return LessonBundelCard(
              lesson: LessonBundelCard.fromJson(snapshot.data.documents[index].data),
              press: () {},
            );
```

Please check out this documentation for details regarding use of fromJson:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Also, you should use different names for the model and the stateless widget.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought no one would help.
now I will try to do as you said

Comment: glad it helped. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped.